# Callback for volley

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My `volley` function wasn't returning a actual `hashmap` full of the items I need.

the function that gets a JSON object from a PHP file, gets the objects, parses it correctly, but the `hashmap` I initially declared isn't being created correctly.

So after researching I realised i need to make a callback for my volley, I found some tutorials, but I still cant manage to do it, it would be really appreciated if someone could help a fellow newb out...Thanks so much!

```js
public HashMap< String,Integer> makeHashMap(final Context C,){
        final HashMap< String,Integer> hm = new HashMap< String,Integer>(); // intilaizaiton to empty hashmap
        final String httpUpdateRoutines = "some php file here ";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(C);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, httpUpdateRoutines, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                
               
                try{
                    JSONArray dataJsonArr = new JSONArray(response);
                    // loop through all users
                    for(int i=0;i<dataJsonArr.length();i++){
                        JSONObject c=dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name=c.getString("name");
                      
                        hm.put(name,i+1); // fill hashmap 
               
                        reversedHashMap.put(i+1, name); //ignore this declear elsewhere

                    }
                    Log.e("sizeofhasmapinrequest", String.valueOf(hm.size()));


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(C, "Data Not Published " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams () throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("type","query");
                return map;

            }


        };
        queue.add(request);
        Log.e("sizeofhashmapbyrequest2", String.valueOf(hm.size())); // returns 0
        return hm;
    }
```

And not marking it final/ moving it to the global space at the top of the class wont work, becuase its accessed as a subclass so it cant be marked final, and the global space wont let it be intialized to the correct value

Comment: have you tried to make `hm` not final ?

Comment: It is used in a subclass which means it has to be marked final. "error: local variable hm is accessed within inner class; needs to be decleared final"